# How can I use [20]bytes type as parameter instead of []bytes in crypto.rand.Read?

Tags: arrays, random, go, cryptography

I want to read random values into a byte array. It works like this:

```
hash = make([]byte,20)
_, err := rand.Read(hash)
```

But I want to do something like

```
var hash [20]byte
_, err := rand.Read(hash)
```

which results in a

```
cannot use hash (type [20]byte) as type []byte in argument to "crypto/rand".Read
```

How can I use a [20]byte with rand.Read?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a slice that is backed by an array, you can write e.g. `hash[i:j]` (which returns a slice from index `i` to index `j-1`). In your case, you can write:

```
var hash [20]byte
_, err := rand.Read(hash[0:20])
```

or, since the default endpoints are `0` and the array-length:

```
var hash [20]byte
_, err := rand.Read(hash[:])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can slice it ([see playground](http://play.golang.org/p/cv9emWM305)):

```
shash := hash[:]
rand.Read(shash)
```

As mentioned in [Go Slices: usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals):

> The start and end indices of a slice expression are optional; they default to zero and the slice's length respectively.